# Calculate$ \frac{17}{75×76}+\frac {17×18}{75×76×77}+\frac {17×18×19}{75×76×77×78}+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

While doing questions on series,I got stuck on this question which says to evaluate

S=$\frac{17}{75×76}+\frac {17×18}{75×76×77}+\frac {17×18×19}{75×76×77×78}+...$

I first tried to convert them in terms of factorials

$\frac {S16!}{74!}=\frac{17!}{76!}+\frac{18!}{77!}+\frac{18!}{78!}+...$

$\frac {S16!}{74!}=  \sum_{k=17}^{\infty}\frac {k!}{(k+59)!}$

$\frac {S16!}{74!}=  \sum_{k=17}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)...(k+59)}$

After partial fraction, It becomes big!

Can anybody help me out!

Comment: Coincidentally, Fematika on YouTube found the value for this exact series. A video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hz0BBYYSC5Q

Comment: Look very long question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Let

$$\prod_{r=1}^{59}\dfrac1{k+r}=f(k)-f(k+1)$$

$$\implies\sum_{17}^n\prod_{r=1}^{59}\dfrac1{k+r}=f(17)-f(n+1)$$

where $f(m)=\displaystyle\prod_{r=1}^{58}\dfrac a{m+r}$

$$f(k)-f(k+1)=\prod_{r=1}^{59}\dfrac{a(k+59-k-1)}{k+r}$$

So, $58a=1$

Now establish $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n+1)=0$