# How to find the sum of $\frac{1}{(1)(3)} + \frac{2}{(1)(3)(5)} +\frac{3}{(1)(3)(5)(7)} +\cdots$ up to n terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How do I find the sum upto n terms of the following series $$\frac{1}{(1)(3)} + \frac{2}{(1)(3)(5)} +\frac{3}{(1)(3)(5)(7)} +\cdots$$

I found the nth term to be $\frac{n}{(1)(3)(5)\cdots(2n+1)}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3662923/calculate-frac1775%c3%9776-frac-17%c3%971875%c3%9776%c3%9777-frac-17%c3%9718%c3%971975%c3%9776%c3%9777%c3%9778

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Like [Calculate$ \frac{17}{75×76}+\frac {17×18}{75×76×77}+\frac {17×18×19}{75×76×77×78}+...$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3662923/calculate-frac1775%c3%9776-frac-17%c3%971875%c3%9776%c3%9777-frac-17%c3%9718%c3%971975%c3%9776%c3%9777%c3%9778)

let
$$\dfrac n{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot(2n-1)(2n+1)}=f(n)-f(n+1)$$

where $f(m)=\dfrac a{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot(2m-1)}$

Using [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)
$$\sum_{r=1}^n\dfrac r{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot(2r-1)(2r+1)}=f(1)-f(n+1)$$

Again, $$f(n)-f(n+1)=\dfrac{a(2n+1)-a}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot(2n-1)(2n+1)}$$

We need $2a=1$